# What happens when an update to a steam game comes out while Im downloading this game?

Tags: steam

Let's say I'm downloading a game over night and in the middle of a night, during downloading, new update to this game comes out. What happens ? Does my download stop ? Does it download but later I have the game in an old version without this update ? Or does the update download for me once the initial downloading of the game is finished and everything is fine after that - my game works properly in the latest version like everyone else's ?

Comment: I can't speak with certainty so this isn't an answer, but the way most programs work is that the base part of the software is downloaded, whether that being just an installer or simple part of the game, then it will download and install the latest version at the time. If it is downloading 2.4 and 2.5 comes out while 2.4 is being downloaded, it will usually continue to download 2.4.

Comment: In my experience, your current download will continue, but you will have another download start after the first is complete.

Comment: @Powerlord I think you can post that as an answer. There might not be any official source, but I think that's what most users know will happen.

Answer (score 3):

Last I checked your download will continue even though a new version is available. The next update will be queued after it and it should go automatically, as long as you haven't restricted automatic updates in the Steam Downloads settings.